# Authentication using API Request

Tags: python, http, python-3.x, http-request

I'm currently writing a short script using the Request API and I need to access my e-mail box in order to retrieve some information.

So I wrote this code in order to authenticate:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import requests

payload = {'horde_user': '',
           'horde_pass': '',
           'login_post': '1'}


r = requests.post('http://webmail.technion.ac.il/login.php', data=payload)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Obviously I replaced `horde_user` by my username and `horde_pass` by my password in the `payload` dictionary.

But the output is the source code of the initial page, while I expected it to be the content of my mail box.

And the status code is 200 while it is supposed to be 302. Could somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Try requesting the page first and then pulling out the session ids from that first request to be used in the login attempt.
  I bet it is failing because you're sending old session ids and the website is rejecting them and sending you back to the login page with a new session id.  The session ids would be `Horde` and `horde_secret_key` in the cookies.

Comment: when i try to log in i get a 200 and an error message that my username / password seems to be wrong (obviously) so could you maybe provide a test account? also write `r.text` to a .html file and open it. maybe youll see the error then.

Comment: If you look at the source of the page, you'll see that there are some hidden inputs - try to include them in the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try requesting the page first and then pulling out the session ids from that first request to be used in the login attempt. I bet it is failing because you're sending old session ids and the website is rejecting them and sending you back to the login page with a new session id. The session ids would be Horde and horde_secret_key in the cookies.

Comment: Could you get me a test account or some sort of valid credentials?  I can't experiment without any means of logging in.

Comment: Sweet deal!! Glad I could help